ArcGIS Online WMS GetFeatureInfo request
At the moment I'm trying to add a WMS in ArcGIS Online and I can't seem to figure out how to make a GetFeatureInfo call.
Using it in the URL does not work for me as ArcGIS Online does not accept this I guess?
I got a OGC WMS from a GeoServer, the service is showing in the online webmap of ArcGIS Online. However I'm not able to get the features into a popup. I reckon there has to be a additional parameter that you can use in ArcGIS Online configuration of a WMS, however I can't find any documentation with direct parameters and how to use them. Does someone have this documentation for me? Or a direct answer?

When you say using it in the URL to what are you referring?  Generally you need to give just the WMS endpoint URL (i.e. with no parameters) to your client (ArcGIS online) when specifying a WMS, and let the client work out all the parameters.    The parameters for a GetFeatureInfo request are exactly the same as a GetMap request, except the request is GetFeatureInfo instead of GetMap, and you must also provide parameters that specify the point in the map image (i/j or x/y) for the query and the format of the returned feature information

It may be that the layer in the WMS is not queryable, and that is why you get no results. You can check by looking at the GetCapabilities response for the service/layer of interest.   for example <Layer queryable="1" means you can query the layer
